# Two procedures with same name & select types but EF complains about incompatible data reader

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two same procedures in two DB, by same I mean:

- Same name
- Same parameters name & type
- End with a select returning same columns types & names (If I put a `SELECT ... INTO table` it generates the exactly same table).

The only thing which differs is the code building the sql query for the final select.
If I use EF on Database 1 it works as intended, but if I run the code on Database 2 it ends on error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Ctx.Procedure_Result'. A member of the type, 'FooId', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

I'm using:

- Entity Framework 4.2
- Visual Studio 2010
- Sql Server 2008 R2

I don't have enough knowledge of EF internals to understand why this is happening.
My idea is that there must be some columns types/names sniffing mecanism which doesn't sniff the same stuff.

Edit 1:

The procedure doesn't "return" a table type it just "select" some rows.
This select result is mapped to a ComplexType in the EDMX.

Feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: Post relevant parts of the code in question? Also the queries and tables?

Comment: In the selected recordset is there the `FooId` column - as you can see in the exception this is the missing column. Another thing that may happen if you have some logic inside the stored procedure is that you may return no results (as opposed to the empty recordset) which would mean that you have no columns at all. Use Sql Profiler to trace the query sent by the EF to the database that "does not work" and run the query manually and see results. I have a feeling you have different data in two databases and as a result the stored procedure behaves differently.

Comment: Ok guys my fault, as suggested I traced the EF queries with SQL Server Profiler. In fact EF was using NULL in a parameter which destroyed the sql query inside the procedure ('select ... ' + NULL => NULL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fault, as suggested I traced the EF queries with SQL Server Profiler.

In fact EF was using NULL in an optional parameter which destroyed the sql query inside the procedure ('select ... ' + NULL => NULL).

With a NULL query the procedure select no column at all and it crashes the EF data reader.